# Converting pounds to grams

Tags: units

I wanted to figure out how many grams were to a lb and instead of looking it up I used my textbook and found 1 kg = 1000 g and 1 kg = 2.205 lb. I set up a cross multiplication equation to solve for *x*. The number I got was close but off by a few hundredths. I got 453.5147 g = 1 lb. I looked to see if I was right and found that the actual number is 453.59 g to lb. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I respect the effort in asking and answering your own question, but unit conversions are not within the purview of this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about chemistry.

Comment: http://chemistry.bd.psu.edu/jircitano/sigfigs.html.

Comment: Google says that 1 kg is 2.20462 pounds. Which is 0.2% off of what you wrote. That means that your converted answer will also be off by ~0.2%.

Answer (score 1):

1kg = 2.20462lb. Textbook just rounded.